# Should I unit test functions for edge cases that won't occur in my application?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

So suppose I have a function in my code like this:

```
const getAccountName = account => `${account.name} ${account.lastName}`;
```

Now, in the function I'm not doing something like `${account?.name ?? ''}` because in this particular case I'm 100% sure that account will always have a `name` and `lastName`.

Now in the unit test for the `getAccountName`, should I still test with an empty object, or without passing any arguments, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the function to be used outside of your package, generally you should expect someone may call it incorrectly
However, if it does not break something of fail you generally don't have to, as thrown `Error` and `undefined` in text is easier to find

If you would write in Typescript, you wouldn't need to check that at all, as if you define function as

```
const getAccountName = (account: {name: string, lastName: string}) => `${account.name} ${account.lastName}`;
```

you may expect that noone will to call it incorrectly (but out-of-package safety checks may still be required)

Answer (score 0):

> because in this particular case I'm 100% sure that account will always have a name and lastName

It's always a judgement call, but I find that in a sufficiently large application, we're only ever "100% sure that X will always have Y... *right now*".  In three years when some project manager decides "an account can now belong to multiple people", and now you have `account.accountHolders[0].name`, how will your function respond?

This is also where a typed language (e.g. typescript) is far more useful than unit tests.  Ideally you'd have

```
const getAccountName = (account: { name: string, lastName: string }) => `${account.name} ${account.lastName}`;
```

And *then* when account becomes `{accountHolders: { name, lastName }}`, the code that does `getAccountName(account)` will cause a compilation error.

Either that or an integration test, something along the lines of

```
function testAccountCreation() {
    const account = createAccount('John', 'Doe')
    assert.Equal(getAccountName(account, 'John Doe'))
}
```

so that you both test both the usage of getAccountName, and the assumption that it depends on (an account has a name and lastName).

Comment: So assuming that I won't use TS here.. (the app is big enough now, and migrating to TS is not a business priority), what would be the best course of action?

Comment: I'd write an integration test that includes `getAccountName` - test that you can both create an account, *and* then call `getAccountName` with that account and get the expected result.  That effectively tests that the assumption "an account has a name and lastName" holds true, which is the implied assumption of that function.  *Or* decide that the chance of that assumption becoming not true is sufficiently low that it doesn't warrant testing.  As I said, it's always a judgement call.